# Coffeescript: Array element matches another array

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have two arrays:

```
array1 = ["hello","two","three"]
array2 = ["hello"]
```

I want to check if array2 contains 1 or more array1 words.

How can I do that using Coffeescript?

Answer (score 12):

Found a way to check for the intersection between two arrays using this CoffeeScript [chapter](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/arrays/using-arrays-to-swap-variables). CoffeeScript seems pretty awesome looking at this.

If the array resulting after the intersection of the elements contains at least one item, then both arrays have common element(s).

```
intersection = (a, b) ->
  [a, b] = [b, a] if a.length > b.length
  value for value in a when value in b

x = ["hello", "two", "three"]
y = ["hello"]

intersection x, y  // ["hello"]
```

Try it [here](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#try%3a%20%20%20%20intersection%20%3D%20%28a%2C%20b%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Ba%2C%20b%5D%20%3D%20%5Bb%2C%20a%5D%20if%20a.length%20%3E%20b.length%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%20for%20value%20in%20a%20when%20value%20in%20b%0A%0A%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%20%5B%22hello%22%2C%20%22two%22%2C%20%22three%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20y%20%3D%20%5B%22hello%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%28intersection%20x%2C%20y%29).

Comment: Hmmm, I am quite confused by the first line, and one of the core benefits of CoffeeScript was supposed to be increased clarity and readability of JS, right? Perhaps this is a case of some code that is clever-but-complicated, and should only be used if it actually more efficient that the clearer code which @alessioalex supplied.

Comment: @GregL - do you mean this line - `intersection = (a, b) ->`?

Comment: Sorry, no, I meant line #2, which is the first line of the intersection function. I have learnt just enough CS syntax so far to be able to read the first line. :-) It's more that I don't understand how that line "works".

Comment: line 2 just swaps a and b, if necessary, to make sure that b is longer than a. This reduces the number of iterations in the for-loop that follows. I find that quite legible actually (the for-loop with its implicit comprehension and return is more confusing).

Comment: @GregL - It's just a parallel assignment that few languages support to swap the values of two variables without requiring a third temporary variable. I agree though that the syntax is a bit non-intuitive, maybe because of the brackets that resemble an Array. In Ruby, we could do the same using - `a, b = b, a if (a.length > b.length)`. The construct of putting the if conditional at the end of a statement in Ruby is something I've started to love. In JavaScript, these are known as [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Avoiding_temporary_variables).

Answer (score 7):

Thought I would throw my own coffeescript one-liner madness :-P

```
true in (val in array1 for val in array2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
(true for value in array1 when value in array2).length > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
contains = (item for item in array2 when item in array1)
```

(reverse the arrays to show double entries in `array1`)

Answer (score 1):

I've made a function is_in, look at my example:

```
array1 = ["hello","two","three"]
array2 = ["hello"]

is_in = (array1, array2) ->
  for i in array2
    for j in array1
      if i is j then return true

console.log is_in(array1, array2)
```

[Test here](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#try%3aarray1%20=%20%5B%22hello%22,%22two%22,%22three%22%5D%0Aarray2%20=%20%5B%22hello%22%5D%0Ais_in%20=%20%28array1,%20array2%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20for%20i%20in%20array2%0A%20%20%20%20for%20j%20in%20array1%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20i%20is%20j%20then%20return%20true%0Aconsole.log%20is_in%28array1,%20array2%29)

After having a look at the intersection example, I can achieve this in another way:

```
intersection = (a, b) ->
  [a, b] = [b, a] if a.length > b.length
  return true for value in a when value in b

array1 = ["hello","two","three"]
array2 = ["hello"]

console.log intersection(array1, array2)
```

[Test here](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#try%3aintersection%20=%20%28a,%20b%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%5Ba,%20b%5D%20=%20%5Bb,%20a%5D%20if%20a.length%20%3E%20b.length%0A%20%20return%20true%20for%20value%20in%20a%20when%20value%20in%20b%0A%0Aarray1%20=%20%5B%22hello%22,%22two%22,%22three%22%5D%0Aarray2%20=%20%5B%22hello%22%5D%0A%0Aconsole.log%20intersection%28array1,%20array2%29)

Comment: The former is much easier to understand - I would be curious if someone wanted to create a jsPerf.com test for this to see if there is any benefit to the intersection code you posted second.

Comment: You can create a jsPerf test yourself. Click on the two 'Test here' links and then grab the compiled JavaScript code from there. After that create a jsPerf with the 2 cases.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone comes here and is looking for the difference as opposed to the intersection

```
difference = (val for val in array1 when val not in array2)
```

This will give you an array (*difference*) of all values in *array1* but not in *array2*